# Using BibTeX in TeXMaker to compile article using journal bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, bibliographystyle

I am trying to prepare an article for submission to a journal which states that the bibliography should be compiled with BibTeX using their journal bibliography style, i.e. I have a JournalDocumentClass.cls file and a JournalBibliographyStyle.bst file. According to the template, I should be able to create my list of references using the following MWE

```
\documentclass{JournalDocumentClass}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}

\title{Title}

\author{Author name}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Sample text \cite{ref1} more sample text ...

\bibliographystyle{JournalBibliographyStyle}
\bibliography{MyBibFile}

\end{document}
```

where MyBibFile.bib is the .bib file in which I have assorted my references with citation keys, e.g. "ref1". When I try to compile using PDFLaTeX + BibTeX + PDFLaTeX + PDFLaTeX + PDFViewer, I get the error

```
ERROR - Cannot find control file 'filename.aux.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX? INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

Does it have anything to do with the fact that in the TexMaker commands panel, my Bib(la)tex row is set to "biber" %.aux (see screenshot attached)?

The instructions on the journal website also mention that a .bib, a .bst, and a .sty file are needed, but a .sty file is not provided in the journal template. However, since the template does explicitly include "\usepackage{natbib}", I have downloaded the natbib.sty file and added it to the folder that contains the .tex and auxiliary files.

How can I fix the compilation error?

[image]

Comment: You are trying to use biber rather than bibtex to set up the bibliography.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. It's currently compiling using biber (see screenshot above), but I would like it to compile using BibTeX instead.